# How to add client authentication filter for spring security oauth2?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm getting error at `/oauth/token`

> InsufficientAuthenticationException: There is no client
>   authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter

I think `@EnableAuthorizationServer` is supposed to add the client authentication filter automatically. But I guess I may be wrong.

I use `authorization_code` grant type, and sending `client_id` and `client_secret` to the `/oauth/token` endpoint

---

```
@Configuration
//@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence.properties" })
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
      oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients(); // here
      // oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
      //   .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("datastore -------------------------------");
        clients.jdbc(dataSource());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        final TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer()));
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(false);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(final DataSource dataSource) {
        final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        // initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
        return initializer;
    }

    // private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
    //     final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    //     populator.addScript(schemaScript);
    //     populator.addScript(dataScript);
    //     return populator;
    // }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource());
    }

}
```

Below is what I believe relavant log when server boots up..

> 21:22:37.255 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain
>   - Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/oauth/token'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key'], Ant [pat
>   tern='/oauth/check_token']]],
>   [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5c6550ae,
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@677898f5,
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@18e1f570,
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7e03993d,
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter@5070db79,
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@29d6f4f9,
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@655e2b00,
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7c056bcc,
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@160d9365,
>   org

Comment: @JEY yes, `/oauth/authorize` is requested first.

Comment: Please attach your requests for `/authorize` and `/token` (uri, query parameters, headers, etc)

Comment: Yes I believe I'm doing that, `{'headers': {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': 'Basic MGQ3MTk2ODUtYzBjMi00YzdiLTkwNWQtMDFmNmZlMzY1ZTg3OjgzZjJmNzNlLTNmY2EtNGQ4NC1iZDJiL\
ThlMDgwZTdiZWJhYQ=='}, 'auth': None, 'data': {'client_id': '0d719685-c0c2-4c7b-905d-01f6fe365e87', 'code': '7L5vx7', 'client_secret': '83f2f73e-3fca-4d84-bd2b-8e080e7bebaa', 'grant_type': 'authorizatio\
n_code', 'redirect_uri': 'http://zibann.kr:10001/complete/test-client/'}, 'method': 'POST'}` . python requests library would handle above params.

Comment: @dur I just solved it.. `http://example.com:10021/oauth/token` I had to remove the ending slash when requesting ... grrrrrrr.. Thanks for help!!!